# Applying AutoNumeric.js to an entire class

Tags: javascript

I would love if someone could help me with what i thought would be a simple application of AutoNumeric.js. I have the below code:

Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/yu1s9nrv/8/

```
<table id="shareInput" class="table_standard">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Growth</th>
    <th>Yield</th>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="input_field_large" id="shareName" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="input_field_medium_num" id="shareQty" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="input_field_medium_dollar" id="sharePrice" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="input_field_medium_pct" id="shareGrowth" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="input_field_medium_pct" id="shareYield" value=""></td>


  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="input_field_large" id="shareName" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="input_field_medium_num" id="shareQty" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="input_field_medium_dollar" id="sharePrice" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="input_field_medium_pct" id="shareGrowth" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="input_field_medium_pct" id="shareYield" value=""></td>

  </tr>
</table>

<script>
  window.onload = function() {


    const anElement = new AutoNumeric('.input_field_medium_pct', 0, {
      suffixText: "%"
    });

  };

</script>
```

The output I expect is for *all* the fields with the class input_field_medium_pct to have the desired AutoNumeric formatting, however it only formats the first field with that class. The documentation reads:

> // The AutoNumeric constructor class can also accept a string as a css
>   selector. Under the hood this use `QuerySelector` and limit itself to
>   only the first element it finds. anElement = new
>   AutoNumeric('.myCssClass > input'); anElement = new
>   AutoNumeric('.myCssClass > input', { options });

Taken from: https://github.com/autoNumeric/autoNumeric#initialize-one-autonumeric-object

I'm new to JS the and find the AutoNumeric documentation notes to be slightly confusing, has anyone run into this issue or able to shed some light on why this might be the case? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `Autonumeric.multiple` to apply it to multiple elements as once.

```
 const anElement =  AutoNumeric.multiple('.input_field_medium_pct', 0, {
      suffixText: "%"
 });
```

Check the [working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2x6z9fc1/)

Also, check the documentation https://github.com/autoNumeric/autoNumeric#initialize-multiple-autonumeric-objects-at-once